# How do you move a pictureBox across a painted panel without any flicker?

Tags: c#, winforms, flicker

I have been using a **doublebuffered** panel to paint images onto itself, but when I move a pictureBox across it, it flickers and lags.

The code I've been using to move pictureBoxes is:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    x = e.X;
    y = e.Y;
    panel1.Invalidate();
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        pictureBox1.Left += (e.X - x);
        pictureBox1.Top += (e.Y - y);
    }
}

private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureBox2.BackgroundImage, new Rectangle(pictureBox2.Location, pictureBox2.Size));       
}
```

as you can see pictureBox2 which isn't visible gets painted to the doublebuffered panel. When I move pictureBox1 however it flickers across the panel. And yes I have been using **Invalidate() panel**

The **doublebuffered panel class** code I use is:

```
public class DoubleBufferPanel : Panel
{


    public DoubleBufferPanel()
    {

        // Set the value of the double-buffering style bits to true.
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;



        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.UserPaint |
         ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);

        this.UpdateStyles();

    }

}
```

Here is a picture of what I am trying to achieve without any flicker.(The pictureBoxes not being moved by the mouse are getting painted to the panel). I can't do this without seeing flicker
[image]

Comment: This is inevitable, double-buffering actually makes it worse.  The only way to completely get rid of it is by not using extra controls.  You don't really need them, you already have a panel that can do the painting.  You'll however have to add the code to do mouse hit testing and keeping track of the image position.

Comment: are you saying to just use panel1's Mouse_down and Mouse_move events?

Answer (score 0):

It lags because you call `Invalidate` instead of `Refresh`. Try to set double buffering on Form as well. If it doesn't help, read some tutorials about custom controls.  [LINK](http://www.google.be/search?q=flickering%20custom%20controls%20c#)